# jQuery fade toggle multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to set up a toggle where when one div is toggled to visible, the other will toggle to hidden. Clicking on "trigger one" toggles div "one" and clicking on "trigger two" toggles div "two". I'm basically looking for a way to make sure that only one of the divs is visible at one time (div one and div two should never both be visible, although both can be hidden).

I'm assuming some kind of if statement but my javascript is not great! Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<a id="trigger-one" href="#">Trigger one</a>
<a id="trigger-two" href="#">Trigger two</a>

<div class="one">Here's one</div>
<div class="two">Here's two</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#trigger-one" ).click(function() {
      $( ".one" ).fadeToggle( "125", "swing" );
      return false;
    });
});     

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#trigger-two" ).click(function() {
      $( ".two" ).fadeToggle( "125", "swing" );
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $('div').eq($(this).index()).fadeToggle("125", "swing");
    $('div:not(":eq('+$(this).index()+')")').fadeOut()
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fvfsfhj7/)

Comment: This works, but only if these are the only "a"s and "div"s on the whole site. How can I do the same but target only the relevant classes?

Comment: It would be easier if your divs shared a common class (classes are meant for that anyway). Then you could replace `$("a").click` with `$("#trigger-one, #trigger-two").click`

Comment: Sorry, would you mind putting this up on jsFiddle? I can't seem to make it work properly if I set it up that way. Thanks!